# How to Render React to an ID with Hooks on an HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

Just learning the hook side of things with React. The class components makes sense, but Hooks are missing the render section.

If I'm adding React to a web page, (NOT THE CREATE REACT APP), how do I let my hook know where to run on the HTML page?

I'm trying to place code inside the following:
`<script src="react-hooks.js"></script>`

Here's my hook code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                Click Me
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

However, there's no place in a hook to say this anywhere.
I've tried this:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById("hook-section");
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, rootElement);
```

but I get the following error:

> quote Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module >quote

If I update the script call to include `type="module"`n I get the following:

> quoteAccess to script at 'file:///C:/Users...react-hooks.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
>   index.html:44
>
> quoteGET file:///C:/Users/.../react-hooks.js net::ERR_FAILED

Classes still work just fine, but not hooks.
I am adding js files in a /src file, which when I run babel, it creates a another js version on the root.

I went off the React docs for this.
https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Step 1: `Run npm init -y (if it fails, here’s a fix)`

Step 2: `Run npm install babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3`

`npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***UPDATE***

Ok, so the solution was setting the type=module in package.json, but now you have a new problem, a CORS error.

You are attempting the load the file from your local filesystem.   Do you have a web server running on your local machine?   If not, you need to set up a basic server locally to fix the CORS error.   Alternatively, you could host the project through a hosting platform such as GitHub.

---

**Verify that you have the latest version of Node installed.** 
You can update your version of node with:

`nvm install 12.16.1`

`nvm use 12.16.1`

The --experimental-modules flag is no longer necessary. Simply do one of the following:

**Add "type": "module" to the nearest parent package.json**. With this, all .js and .mjs files are interpreted as ES modules.

*package.json*

```
{
    "type":"module"
}
```

**OR**

**Explicitly name files with the .mjs extension.** All other files, such as .js will be interpreted as CommonJS, which is the default if type is not defined in package.json.

`mv react-hooks.js react-hooks.mjs`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @Mitchell Updated answer, can you try my suggestions please

Comment: How do you actually do that? If I go into my packages.json and type anything in, I get errors, no matter where I would add:
{
   "type": "module"
}

Comment: @Mitchell npm !== node.js !!  You updated NPM,  you need to update Node if your version is less than 12.16.1.    You would add "type" : "module" at the top level of package.json.  If "type" is already set to "commonJS" then change it to module.   Also, you could rename your .js file to have a .mjs extension.

Comment: Node is at v13.6.0

Comment: OK great,  so you should be good by setting type in package.json.  As stated it needs to be the nearest parent package.   Or just rename your .js file to .mjs  (<-- seems easier)

Comment: ```
"type": "module",
  "name": "react-learning",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "like_button.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },```

That's the only way I can add module. Still nothing

Comment: Also changed the filename from .js to .mjs, and it's still not working.

Comment: OK, sorry I missed that type=module gets you a CORS error.  Please have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I do need a server to get any of this to display. I wish I saw something like this in the React docs.